# Width: calc() on img is not relative to parent container

Tags: html, css, image, calc

I'm currently working on a layout where I have to use negative margins on the images. The images are inside `<div class="entry-content">`, which has a padding. To make the images within `entry-content` go outside the paddings, I use negative margins. To stretch the image outside the `<div class="entry-content">` I used  `width:calc(100%+margin)`.

This doesn't work as expected though - the 100% seems to be the image's width rather than the width of `entry-content`. I want the image's width to be relative to `entry-content`, as the image will be used in a responsive layout.

I'm currently very early in the process, so I still have a fixed width on `body`.

HTML

```
<!-- other unrelated code such as header-->
<div class="entry-content">
    <p>
        <img src="http://www.hellothere.se/blog/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/TKD-Promo-title-940x400.jpg" />
    </p>
</div>
```

CSS

```
body {
  width: 340px;
}

.entry-content{
  padding: 0 0.75em;
  position: relative;
}

.entry-content img {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 -0.75em;
  width: calc(100%+0.75em);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> [**MDN `calc()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc):
>
> The `+` and `-` operators **must always be surrounded by whitespace**. The operand of `calc(50% -8px)` for instance will be parsed as a percentage followed by a negative length, an invalid expression, while the operand of `calc(50% - 8px)` is a percentage followed by a minus sign and a length. Even further, `calc(8px + -50%)` is treated as a length followed by a plus sign and a negative percentage.
>   The `*` and `/` operators do not require whitespace, but adding it for consistency is allowed, and recommended.

The `+` operator must be surrounded by whitespace.

Therefore it should be `width: calc(100% + 0.75em)` rather than `calc(100%+0.75em)`

```css
body {
    width:340px;
}
.entry-content {
    padding: 0 0.75em;
    position:relative;
}
.entry-content img {
    display:block;
    margin: 0 -0.75em;
    width: calc(100% + 0.75em);
}
```

```html
<div class="entry-content">
    <p>
        <img src="//placehold.it/200" />
    </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Oh. My. God. It was that simple... Thank you! The thought didn't even occur to me as it seemed, well, too simple.