# in css how to reduce padding of an element

Tags: css

I am using an external CSS stylesheet for my app. For certain pages, I want to reduce the padding defined in that library for list items. Something like:

```
.class-name-xyz .special-marker-class {
   padding: an algebraic operation on <<class-name-xyz::padding>>
}
```

(I don't even know if this is feasible in CSS.)

Thanks

Comment: Sorry but I didn't get it. Could you elaborate?

Comment: Aside from using `calc()`, what you're trying to do is not possible unless you use relative units or something along those lines.

Comment: @Josh how does that work? I tried `.item.special-marker-class {padding:calc(100%-10px);}` but not the item is invisible is Chrome. If I uncheck that style, the item shows up. Do I need to enable something else?

Comment: @Hasheem, I do not want to hardcode a value but only make the items *relatively* more compact on display. So if original was `.item{padding:16px;}` then I want `.item.my-class` to be 80% of that

Comment: @Dinesh Maybe this answer will be relevant to you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28488004/width-calc-on-img-is-not-relative-to-parent-container/28488053#28488053

Comment: @Dinesh Unfortunately, `calc()` doesn't allow you to access the *existing* styles.. the *relative* part you are talking about wouldn't be possible (if you mean *relative* to the existing `padding`).

Comment: @Josh this is great, thanks! Despite the limitations, I am still better off than before. I did indeed mean relative to existing padding.